# Changing Cell Value based on formula

Tags: excel, vba

The following script works fine when the value in a cell in column AC is changed manually. How can this script be modified so that it works when the cell value in column AC is changed by a formula?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AC:AC")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("AD" & Target.Row) = Range("AC" & Target.Row)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use Worksheet_Calculate event.  But there is no `Target` in that so it will repopulate every time it calculates.  But there is no reason for vba in this case as you are basically doing `=AC3` for `AD3`.

Comment: The issue is that I can not enter a formula in column AD. The ultimate goal is if a user has manually entered a value in a cell column AD then this value should not a overwritten when the value of the cell in column AC changes. However if the cell in column AD is null then it should be populated with the corresponding value from the cell in column AC each time the cell value in column AC changes. The value in column AC is changed by formula.

Comment: Your code above does not test whether there is data in AD before overwriting it.  Hence the recommendation.

Comment: Then it would be better if you used a third column for your manual entry and then used a formula to check if there is a value in that column and if so use it, if not use the value in AC.  Most formulas calculate only when the data to which the refer changes.  Using a Worksheet_Calculate event would force an iteration of every cell in the column.